# Is possible to disable a link after some time in a newsletter?

Tags: images, links, newsletter

I work in a company where we sent many offer newsletters a week.

When the offer time has passed we replace some of the images of the newsletter so that it is clear the offer has ended.

Lets say that we have an image of the product and of course it has a link to our website. Apart from changing the image with the word "Ended" , **is it possible to disable the link as well**?

I know it might not sound possible, but wondering if there is way.

Comment: In which format newsletters are sent? Emails built on HTML?

Comment: html, based on images though. I use image maps mostly.

Comment: We need some more info about what you are linking to. Are you linking to static html files? PHP files? Direct downloads?

Comment: I am talking about a html newsletter. I have an href link that links to a product on a website. Dont know how I can add more info about this.

Answer (score 2):

If by "disabling the link" you mean reaching into the user's mailboxes and making it so that the `<a>` tag disappears from the message, no.

That being said, all you would need to do to disable or expire a link is redirect its target to some other page of your choosing at the appropriate time.  Consider making a default "Sorry, but this offer has expired" page with links to other areas of your site and using that.